# Significance of Self-Interaction in Hartree Potential

Tags: electromagnetism, density-functional-theory, exchange-interaction

According to DFT (and correct me if I'm incorrect) the terms of Hartree potential and exchange correlation potential are introduced to simulate the particle (fermion-fermion) interaction in our system of N-non interacting bodies. But the Hartree potential also includes the term for fermion interacting by itself.
And the exchange correlation potential being  $$V_{XC}(\textbf{r}) = \frac{\delta E_{XC} (r)}{\delta n(r)}$$
I have 3 questions basically:

Q1. Why is self-interaction necessary?

Q2. What is the significance/meaning of a fermion interacting with itself?

Q3. What is the difference between exchange correlation energy and Hartree energy?

Comment: > *"But the Hartree potential also includes the term for fermion interacting by itself."* Source for this claim? There is no physical self-interaction in exact multi-particle Schroedinger equation. In DFT we make approximations and it may look like there is self-interaction, mathematically. But physically, there is none.

Comment: @JánLalinský https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/768475/coulombic-interaction-in-condensed-matter if you see the given text here which states that $E_{Hartree}$ is denoting the self interaction of electron density. Do correct if my interpretation is incorrect

Comment: That is a Coulomb electrostatic energy of the total charge density, which is due to all electrons. It is self-interaction in the sense there is only single function $n$, interacting with itself in the formula. It has nothing to do with hypothetical physical self-interaction of single fermion with itself.

Comment: Also that "self-interaction" formula replaces the "correct" formula for expected average energy from the exact Schroedinger theory, and the replacement may cause some error in the value. Expectation value of the Coulomb energy of a set of charged particles is not exactly the same thing as Coulomb energy of the average charge density describing the set of charged particles. The difference can be blamed on the self-interaction that is in the formula, but is not real.

Comment: " Expectation value of the Coulomb energy of a set of charged particles is not exactly the same thing as Coulomb energy of the average charge density describing the set of charged particles" Can you give a mathematical basis for this? ALso That only leaves the Q3. of my question.

Comment: I think it's obvious - it's a different formula based on different quantities. The exact formula is sum of expectation values for pairwise potential energy terms, the other is integral of expectation value of charge density.